# Fileupload authentication issue on Websphere 7

Tags: file-upload, websphere, basic-authentication

We are currently facing a production issue on Websphere 7 with respect to richfaces fileupload component. The problem description is that immediately after the file for upload is browsed and selected using this component, the basic authentication dialogbox appears asking for user credentials.

Following are the frameworks we are using in our project:

JSF 1.2 & Richfaces 3.3.3
Spring Framework 3.x
Spring Webflow 2.1
Spring Security 3.x (only basic authentication using login dialogbox)

The user is authenticated once when he wants to access the application at the beginning using basic authentication. All screens that dont use fileupload component are working fine. But if we use fileupload component, as I mentioned above, the file selection (even from local machine path) triggers the basic authentication dialogbox again. The strange thing is that this behaviour does not occur on our Dev Environment which uses Tomcat 6. On Tomcat, the fileupload is not triggering any user login and upload is working fine.

This problem is occuring only when the app. is deployed on Websphere 7. Can anybody please tell whether Websphere requires any additional configuration for accessing Files through this component ?

We have spent a lot of time investigating this problem without any meaningful results. As this is a production issue for us now, it is very critical and needs to be resolved at the earliest.

So please help in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the File Upload component, and the answer may well lie in the detail of how that works, but in general WebSphere will challenge if an HTTP request arrives for a protected resource and the request does not contain a valid LTPA cookie. The cookie is normally sent by the browser on each request when authentication has happended once, BUT it will only do so if it believes that the cookie is related to a given domain. So if the main part of your website were served from, say,

```
htpp://my.own.org.com/mysite
```

and the file upload were related to a subtly different host

```
http://my.other/filesite
```

Then the cookie would not be sent, and a challenge would result.

My approach to diagnosing this would be get some kind of traffic sniffer. See exactly what is flowing and the addresses being used. I'm predicting that you will see the LTPA cookie in the usual case and not in the upload case. Then it's a matter of figuring out "why".

Comment: I'd recommend [LiveHTTPHeaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/installation.html)